# Firefox crashes when started by Selenium firefox driver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, crash

I have call new instance firefox browser by Selenium webdriver

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

but there are a error

> Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>   Application Name: firefox.exe    Application Version: 38.0.1.5611
>   Application Timestamp:    55540a1a   Fault Module Name:   xul.dll    Fault
>   Module Version:   38.0.1.5611   Fault
>   Module Timestamp: 55541969   Exception Code:  c0000005   Exception
>   Offset:   0035669b   OS Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48   Locale ID:  1033
>   Additional Information 1: 0a9e   Additional Information
>   2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional Information 3:    0a9e
>   Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

I must click **close programme** to continue and firefox browser is diplayed

Firefox 38
Selenium 2.45
windown 7 x64 or windown 8 x64

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox crash when I run selenium unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456204/firefox-crash-when-i-run-selenium-unit-test)

Answer (score 31):

I've same problem on **Firefor 47.0 (stub)**. Reinstalling doesn't solve problem.

Update to 47.0.1 or download **[Firefox 45.0](https://www.softexia.com/windows/web-browsers/firefox-45)** and selenium will work

Comment: thanks. upgrading from FF 47.0 to 47.0.1 worked for me

Comment: Works for me for an hour until IT upgrades firefox for me... Is there any way to catch this error or do you just have to live with random crashes?

Answer (score 11):

Seems like a compatibility issue to me. *Firefox 38 is not officially supported by Selenium 2.45*.

Downgrade to 35 or lower from [here](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/). You can also find the `Selenium` changelog [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG). See another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456204/firefox-crash-when-i-run-sellenium-unit-test/30456251#30456251).

Comment: Where can you find which Firefox versions are supported by which Selenium version? I can't seem to locate that information.

Comment: Updated the changelog link. And individual language bindings see [this](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Comment: I got this issue today and downgraded from 47 to 44 and now is working fine.

Comment: Is there any way to catch this error or do you just have to live with random crashes?

Answer (score 3):

Even I was facing the same issue, its related to compatibility issue,I just downloaded latest version of webdriver(i.e Selenium-java-2.46.0) and firefox v 38.0.5, jdk(1.8_31) n it worked.

Comment: true story, learned the hard way that 2.42 is not the same as 2.46

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone has a bugfix in the pipeline for this as well.
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/6fc17a0cba238af9d76f5fe6e32f73ac8958c19e