# Selenium, opening ff browser and automaticly close

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Trying to run testng suite compiled jar on remote linux machine.

Problem I have is, if I run tests, FF open url I have defined and after that closing brower, and so on.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"username"}
```

Selenium 2.53.0
FF 45.0

Any idea why my test just open browser and close?

Comment: Can you share the code relevant to the stack trace?

Comment: If this works on your local machine, the first thing I'd check would be that your Linux machine can access the site you're trying to hit.

Comment: Hi Guys, sorry I was using wrong url without "/" on the end, after I changed all working now.

Comment: If the question is fixed, could you close/remove it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong url without "/" on the end, after I changed all working now.

Answer (score 0):

NoSuchElementException is thrown when element does not exist. It may not be the reason for fx crash.
The possibilities are :

Some where in the code you will be closing the driver.

I had faced the same issue earlier.

Try to upgrade your firefox to the latest version.

Try to set the firefox driver using setProperties

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
WebDriver driver=new  FirefoxDriver();
```

Follow the link to upgrade or downgrade fx: https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Install-and-Update/Install-an-older-version-of-Firefox/ta-p/1564

Below are some of the helpful links.

[Firefox crashes when started by Selenium firefox driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473556/firefox-crashes-when-started-by-selenium-firefox-driver)

[Which Firefox version is compatible with Selenium 2.53.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747430/which-firefox-version-is-compatible-with-selenium-2-53-0)