# Selenium: open a Url on already opened browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to open facebook then I sign in using my credentials and then I want to open a facebook page again. Sometimes it gets open and sometime its not. What could be the problem?

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
fburl = "https://www.facebook.com/"
driver.get(fburl)

assert "Facebook" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
elem.send_keys("XXXX")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
elem.send_keys("XXXX")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# open some fb page
for i in range(len(fbpagelist)):
   fbpageurl = fbpafelist[i]
   driver.get(fbpageurl)
```

I have to open a facebook page on the same browser with logged in Facebook.

Sometimes I can see `fbpageurl` on opened browser but sometimes not.

Comment: What are the symptoms? Any errors? What is happening on the browser side?

Comment: NO errors when I opened a new tab via python code. I can see new open tab. But its showing 'connecting' and cant see URL in address bar.

Comment: What firefox and selenium versions are you using?

Comment: Both I have updated to latest one.But sometimes Its working. Is there any time limit for browser opened by selenium.

Comment: That could be a problem, downgrade firefox to 35.0.1 and check if the issue persists. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456204/firefox-crash-when-i-run-sellenium-unit-test/30456251#30456251 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473556/firefox-is-crash-when-start-by-selenium-firefox-driver.

Comment: I think it depends on how fast can you log in, because after you press the RETURN, you instantly redirect to the fbpageurl. Try to insert a Thread.sleep(1000) or (2000) before the second driver.get().

Comment: @peetya Yes I am using time.sleep(10) for now

Comment: @alecxe I have downgraded my firefox version. Still facing the issue. I am opening a facebook then log in after that I have some 50 pages to check. So for 4-5 pages I can see its working but after that new tab just shows 'connecting'

Comment: This code isn't enough to understand or see the issue. Please minimise it.