# Why does Firefox error message pop up when running Protractor test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am e2e testing an AngularJS app with Protractor.

Each time I run a spec, Firefox opens, quits this pops up:[image]

and then firefox works and the specs run fine. This stays infront of whatever I'm working on after the test and is annoying. Any fixes?

I am running protractor, configured on localhost:4444, and using the firefox browser (firefox 39), and running on mac osx 10.

I saw this posted on the Protractor Github page but no one seems to have an answer for it quite yet so I figured I'd ask here as well.
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2297

Comment: If Firefox is not your main browser you may try to downgrade it (and switch off auto update). Some issues are version specific.

Comment: Thanks. Tried both of these. Seems the error occurs on both firefox 38 and 39.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely due to compatibility issues between your selenium webdriver and Firefox. I've personally had this problem before until I've downgraded Firefox to, at most, [37](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/) and updated selenium webdriver to the latest version (currently [2.46](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md)):

```
webdriver-manager update
```

See also:

- [Firefox crash when I run selenium unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456204/firefox-crash-when-i-run-selenium-unit-test/30456251#30456251)
- [Firefox crashes when started by Selenium firefox driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473556/firefox-crashes-when-started-by-selenium-firefox-driver)